# C# XML Parsing - Searching for specific elements

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

I'm using an `XMLReader` in C# .net 4.0 to search through a small snippet of XML. I want to find specific elements in the XML, and I'm using the `XMLReader.ReadToFollowing("name")` method to find the elements. I do not know the order in the XML document that the elements are; they be in a difference sequence or missing entirely.  The order does not matter to me, but I will throw an exception if the element is missing.

The XMLReader is forward only, so if the first element I'm looking for is the last value in the XML document, additional reads will fail.

I was thinking of creating a new XMLReader for each search. I only have a small set of elements to find and the XML isn't huge so I don't think there will be much overhead, but I could be wrong.

Is there a better library to use for searching XML when you do not know the order of the elements? Or is a lack of order in XML a violation of the XML specification?

Specifically, let's say I have some simple XML. A head and 10 Children.

```
<sometag>
     <element1>data</element1>
     <element2>data</element2>
     .
     .
     .
     <element10>data</element10>
</sometag>
```

Would it be inefficient to open 5 XMLReaders to find those elements? I could also use the one reader and step through each element, but then I would need to keep track of which elements I've found.

Comment: If you have a sample of the XML, there are several ways to do it. I'm sure plenty of people would be happy to post some concrete examples - I know I would! Other ways you could approach this are to use DOM based parsing via XmlDocument and XPath - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument or the more modern XDocument class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of XMLReader you could use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (linq2xml), do it fast and easy (by [`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
var element1 = doc.Element(searchItemName);
if (element1 == null) throw ...
...
return ....;
```

You can call it as many time as you like without reloading xml file.

Comment: Do you think the overhead of creating an XDocument be greater than opening 5 XMLReaders? Where do you think opening $Y XMLReaders would be  slower than XDocument, or is there really not much difference?

Comment: @Rastapopulous, I test it myself before, anyway it's better to learn to work with xdocument and linq, because it's too easy to do anything with xml files which was hard with other xml components, here when your file is small there is no performance difference, but code is really simple, maintenance is easier, and development speed is really faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPath. It is much faster and isn't sensitive to the order of elements (only the hierarchy).

MSDN Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Programming with XPath does require a bit of learning. And if your XML specifies a namespace, you'll need to be sure to include that in your XPath query.

Answer (score 0):

You have .NET 4.0, so use Linq to XML.